# What is the different between echo $(pwd) and echo "$(pwd)"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the different between `echo $(pwd)` and `echo "$(pwd)"`?

I remember that they are the same thing, but the two commands give me different output.

Here is my output:

```
/usr/share/locale ⌚ 21:19:24
$ echo $(pwd)
 usr shar  l cal 

/usr/share/locale ⌚ 21:19:32
$ echo "$(pwd)"
/usr/share/locale
```

It seems like many characters are dropped by `echo $(pwd)`, so many scripts can not be run correctly. For example, I must use `eval "$(something --alias)"` instead of `eval $(something --alias)`.

I tried `echo $(pwd)` and `echo "$(pwd)"` in a docker container, the outputs are same.

Is there something wrong in my system?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all about word splitting, there is a variable named `IFS`: internal field separator, after an expansion or substitution bash will splits the results of that process into different words based on IFS's value.

The default value of this variable is: `"<space><tab><newline>"`, means words separated by space or tab or a newline will be considered and passed as separate words to your command.

So a variable with the value of "hello name is foo", after expansion will be considered as 4 different word:

```
$ printf "%s\n" hello name is foo
hello
name
is
foo
```

If I want to consider it as a single word I should quote it:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "hello name is foo"
hello name is foo
```

If I set the IFS to `/` it will use `/` as field separator, so:

```
$ export IFS='/'
$ var=/some/thing/here
$ echo $var
 some thing here
```

That might be your case (having a `/` in IFS), however if you quote the subsituation like: `"$( ... )"` then bash will skip the word splitting.

then try running your commands again, now it shouldn't use `/` to separate words including in the path (pwd).

Comment: Note that there are two bad practices here: using a variable or command substitution without double-quotes around it, and having `IFS` set to a nonstandard value. Either one alone is a problem waiting to happen; with both together, you're basically guaranteed to get weird results. And BTW `eval` is also unsafe unless you know exactly what you're doing.